# Structure mySQL DB where data could belong in same table but some data is frequently accessed while other data is only for historic reports

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

I have an orders table containing customer orders. A customer can have 1 open order at a time. An open order can be modified by the customer. Once an order is closed it can no longer be modified by the customer and is accessed primarily for reporting. I would prefer to save open orders and closed orders in the same table, but my concern is that over time this table will grow very large and performance will slow down. The reason I want to keep both in the same table is because I need to run reports across both, and having them in the same table is easiest. My question is this: should it really a be a concern that having all records in the same table will slow things down?

I'm determining whether an order is open/closed by an enum field called status. Any order with a status of: "new, queued, packed, suspended" is considered open, while any order with a status of "completed" is considered closed.

Comment: "*should it really a be a concern that having all records in the same table will slow things down?*"—no, it shouldn't.  As the table grows, indexing then partitioning then sharding and clustering should solve most scalability problems.

Comment: I thought about partitioning but I want to have a foreign key referencing an "order_items" table. From what I understand you can't partition a table with any foreign keys right?

Answer (score 0):

Need not necessarily. Depends on cardinality of the relation. As you said in your post, it looks like there is always a `1:1` relation present and in such case you have the status in same table.

Either you can have `Status varchar(10)` column with values `Open/closed` or better have two bit fields saying `IsOpen bit` and `IsClosed bit`.